# Python - get the index of a dictionary (json list) with the highest value of one of the items?

Tags: python, json, list, dictionary, max

I use the TMDB api [tmdbsimple https://pypi.org/project/tmdbsimple/] and it provides me with a json, where I want to extract the 'file_path' of the 'dict posters' item that has the highest number of 'vote_count', how would I do that?

```
import tmdbsimple as tmdb
myKey = '****' #api key https://developers.themoviedb.org/3/getting-started/introduction
tmdb.API_KEY = myKey

tvg_tmdbid = '67158'
lst_posters_mylang = tmdb.TV(tvg_tmdbid).images(language='pt')['posters']
if lst_posters_mylang != []:
    item = ???
    posterpath = lst_posters_mylang[item]['file_path']
```

Note: fixed the print of the variable 'lst_posters_mylang'

print(lst_posters_mylang) return this json:

```
[
    {'aspect_ratio': 0.6666666666666666, 'file_path': '/3o7f2Xjwl5hcoiioR9eGdD9ezHt.jpg', 'height': 2160, 'iso_639_1': 'pt', 'vote_average': 5.312, 'vote_count': 1, 'width': 1440
    },
    {'aspect_ratio': 0.6666666666666666, 'file_path': '/cZy35eGPBcXOagv3ujmfGVm4U1C.jpg', 'height': 2160, 'iso_639_1': 'pt', 'vote_average': 0.0, 'vote_count': 0, 'width': 1440
    },
    {'aspect_ratio': 0.6666666666666666, 'file_path': '/46CmxozfvZSpeg4cEZ86Sm6QOXT.jpg', 'height': 1500, 'iso_639_1': 'pt', 'vote_average': 0.0, 'vote_count': 0, 'width': 1000
    },
    {'aspect_ratio': 0.6666666666666666, 'file_path': '/oWr83fLF26UUn6tPKNMk2U7fqLr.jpg', 'height': 750, 'iso_639_1': 'pt', 'vote_average': 0.0, 'vote_count': 0, 'width': 500
    },
    {'aspect_ratio': 0.66625, 'file_path': '/22YerMIPRTPe4jG1A2a9jgpBWxo.jpg', 'height': 800, 'iso_639_1': 'pt', 'vote_average': 0.0, 'vote_count': 0, 'width': 533
    }
]
```

In this case, item 0 of the 'posters' has the highest 'vote_count' = 1, how do I get this "posters" item value through python?
only then I can get the 'file_path' value:

**item = 0**

posterpath = lstposters_mylang[item]['file_path']

***posterpath ---- '/3o7f2Xjwl5hcoiioR9eGdD9ezHt.jpg'***

Comment: Have you tried anything? It could be as simple as calling max on the poster list. What would happen if multiple entries share the same highest value?

Comment: `max((x['vote_count'], x['file_path']) for x in lst_posters_mylang)[1]` - if the answer is that short and only contains basic Python, you have to ask yourself if you tried hard enough to find an answer before asking on StackOverflow. Try something yourself, ask questions if you have trouble getting it to work - don't ask us to do your work for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed your vote counts just so you can see that it'll sort and find the correct value.

```
data = [
    {'aspect_ratio': 0.6666666666666666, 'file_path': '/3o7f2Xjwl5hcoiioR9eGdD9ezHt.jpg', 'height': 2160, 'iso_639_1': 'pt', 'vote_average': 5.312, 'vote_count': 1, 'width': 1440
    },
    {'aspect_ratio': 0.6666666666666666, 'file_path': '/cZy35eGPBcXOagv3ujmfGVm4U1C.jpg', 'height': 2160, 'iso_639_1': 'pt', 'vote_average': 0.0, 'vote_count': 5, 'width': 1440
    },
    {'aspect_ratio': 0.6666666666666666, 'file_path': '/46CmxozfvZSpeg4cEZ86Sm6QOXT.jpg', 'height': 1500, 'iso_639_1': 'pt', 'vote_average': 0.0, 'vote_count': 6, 'width': 1000
    },
    {'aspect_ratio': 0.6666666666666666, 'file_path': '/oWr83fLF26UUn6tPKNMk2U7fqLr.jpg', 'height': 750, 'iso_639_1': 'pt', 'vote_average': 0.0, 'vote_count': 3, 'width': 500
    },
    {'aspect_ratio': 0.66625, 'file_path': '/22YerMIPRTPe4jG1A2a9jgpBWxo.jpg', 'height': 800, 'iso_639_1': 'pt', 'vote_average': 0.0, 'vote_count': 2, 'width': 533
    }
]
data_tuples = [] # iterate through items and collect tuples of file_path and vote_count
for d in data:
    data_tuples.append((d['file_path'], d['vote_count']))
file_path_max_votes = sorted(data_tuples, key = lambda x: x[1])[-1][0]
# this sorts tuples ascending, [-1] chooses the last tuple in the list; [0] takes the first value of the tuple
```

Output

```
In [164]: file_path_max_votes
Out[164]: '/46CmxozfvZSpeg4cEZ86Sm6QOXT.jpg'
```

Answer (score 0):

Using pythons built-in [sorted](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html), you can define your own sort-criteria via the `key` argument.

By default it'll sort ascending, so you'll want to set `reverse=True`.

Then you can get the first item from the list to get the maximum.

`best_poster = sorted(lst_posters_mylang['posters'], key=lambda bd:bd["vote_count"], reverse=True)[0]`

Sidenote: Empty arrays are false, so you could just do `if lst_posters_mylang:`

Comment: did not work, returned this error: TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str.
I need the 'file_path' with the most votes ('vote_count'), do you know another method? Thanks